# (421) Estouro de Pilha

Tags: novo-recurso, chat

Isso é o que tá na minha aba da nossa digníssima e honrada sala de chat: o [Estouro de Pilha](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha).

Nada de errado com isso. Muito pelo contrário. É sinal do tamanho da comunidade e do tempo que vocês passam aqui. Mas movimento de chat é que nem livro... por melhor que seja ter vários, uma hora você precisa comprar uma estante porque não dá mais pra ficar empilhando na escrivaninha.

[image: Organiza isso aí, faz favor]

O Estouro de Pilha tá chegando próximo dessa bagunça aí em cima, não só em volume de mensagens mas também na variedade de assuntos constantemente discutidos. Só dar uma olhada na média de mensagens/dia pra cada mês desde a criação do SOpt:

[image: Organiza isso aí também, faz favor]

Março chegou na beira de 1000 mensagens/dia. Mil. Um milhar de mensagens todo dia é muita mensagem. As conversas acabam se atropelando, e os assuntos se embolando. Eu entendo que nós não temos tamanho pra dividir nosso chat em dezenas de salas menores por tecnologia, linguagem, filme favorito, etc, como é o caso do SOen, mas podemos dividir pelos 2 maiores assuntos que temos hoje:

1. Programação, e associados
2. O site, as regras, casos para serem discutidos

Dessa maneira nenhum assunto afoga o outro, nem domina um espaço por tempo indeterminado. Você pode conversar sobre Angular e Hibernate em um lugar, e pedir conselho sobre o que fazer com uma pergunta em outro. Todo mundo sai ganhando.

Assim os dois assuntos terão mais oportunidade e espaço para serem discutidos, sem muita pressa, e com mais gente tendo oportunidade de participar - que é a ideia do chat.

Então a partir de agora, vocês tem uma nova sala pra conversar sobre o que acontece no próprio site. Digam olá para o...

### [Debate da Pilha](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57786/debate-da-pilha)<sup><sup>1</sup></sup>

Pra ajudar a manter as coisas em ordem, vigiar um pouco do escopo, e garantir que todo mundo se comporte, o [jbueno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/18246/jbueno) e o [OnoSendai](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/1897/onosendai) foram escolhidos como Room Owners, pelo excelente histórico de civilidade e respeito que tem com comunidade. Parabéns aos dois!

O Estouro de Pilha tem participação mais ativa dos moderadores, então não precisa de mais Room Owners por enquanto, mas é algo que deve acontecer no futuro próximo.

Como linhas gerais, podem ver as duas salas dessa maneira:

- **Estouro de Pilha**: Conversas sobre programação, dúvidas, conselhos em geral e um pouco de conversa fiada porque ninguém é de ferro
- **Debate da Pilha**: Conversas sobre o que fazer com posts; debater a interpretação de regras; conselhos sobre situações que ocorrem no site

Parece-me uma distinção bem clara, mas ampla o suficiente pra que vocês possam adaptá-las às suas necessidades e ideias com o passar do tempo.

Se esforcem para manter as duas salas em mente, e levem numa boa os lembretes ocasionais dos room owners, e de outras pessoas nas salas, para mover a conversa para uma sala ou a outra. O site é um sistema que funciona na base da cordialidade, e depende da boa-vontade de todo mundo.

---

1. Nome não-definitivo. Fiquem a vontade para conversar e mudar.

Comment: Pois é acho que essa pilha estourou.

Comment: Agora vai ter gente com duas abas abertas postando 100 mensagens por dia em cada uma :D. Mas eu apoio a iniciativa, não participo tão ativamente do Chat mas minha experiência mostra que os assuntos estão se atropelando sim.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly A ideia é essa, dividir e conquistar :D

Comment: Depois de certo tempo com o chat ativo, percebo que quase ninguém frequenta ou discute la, sempre as mesmas 3 ou 4 pessoas, enquanto o outro chat tem sempre mais pessoas e discussões. Sei não, na minha opinião essa divisão foi feita cedo demais ou a divulgação foi pouca, eu sempre posto coisas la e quase nunca tenho um feedback de outros membros, parece que postar lá é ficar falando sozinho.

Comment: @diegofm A expectativa nunca foi de que ambos teriam o mesmo nível de participação. A nova sala certamente vai ser menos movimentada e menos ativa que a anterior. Mas se você vir conversas que deveriam estar acontecendo no Debate da Pilha acontecendo no Estouro de Pilha, é responsabilidade sua - e de todos nós - apontar os participantes para a nova sala e incentivar seu uso. Chat é tão "moderado pela comunidade" quanto o site

Comment: @Gabe na verdade me referi a falta de pessoas debatendo na nova sala, o pessoal neste quesito de comportamento é ótimo, cada sala tem sido respeitado sua finalidade. O que deixa a desejar é discussões na sala nova. Parece que o pessoal não está muito interessado nisso, eu posto várias situações lá, é raro eu receber uma segunda opinião.